# Register has "wrong" value in core dump analysed by gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, cpu-registers, coredump

I'm analyzing a core dump file created by SIGSEV using gdb. I get the line number for the C source, but when I evaluate the expression, I get the correct value (the expression is

```
local_var = ((array[index])->field[index2]).field2
```

where `array` is a global variable). The values of `index` and `index2` are optimized out (of course :-( ), but I computed them a couple of times and each time I got the same valid value. Out of despair I've checked the disassembled code and the registers and got this:

```
   0x00002b083e06d84c <+142>:   mov    %r13d,%edx          # index (234) to edx
   0x00002b083e06d84f <+145>:   mov    0x2039fa(%rip),%rax # 0x2b083e271250 (address of array)
   0x00002b083e06d856 <+152>:   mov    (%rax,%rdx,8),%rdx  # array[index] (0x2b083e271250+8*234) to rdx
   0x00002b083e06d85a <+156>:   movslq %ecx,%rax           # index2 to rax
=> 0x00002b083e06d85d <+159>:   mov    0x28(%rdx),%rdx     # array[index]->field to rdx
```

The comments are my understanding of the code. The SIGSEV is received at the last instruction. The contents of the registers:

```
rax            0x5  5
rbx            0x2aaad4096a9c   46913190193820
rcx            0x5  5
rdx            0x0  0
rsi            0xea 234
rdi            0xc75000a9   3343909033
rbp            0x41f898c0   0x41f898c0
rsp            0x41f898a0   0x41f898a0
r8             0x2aaacb411c60   46913042848864
r9             0x2020202020207475   2314885530818475125
r10            0x52203c3c20202020   5917796139299512352
r11            0x2b083bb29070   47314361290864
r12            0xc75000a9   3343909033
r13            0xea 234
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x2aaad40966a4   46913190192804
rip            0x2b083e06d85d   0x2b083e06d85d
```

Because `rdx` is 0, I understand the segmentation fault in the last segment, because the code tried to read from `0x28` which is not accessible. What I don't understand is why `rdx` is 0? In the first line `edx` gets the `234` value (the `r13` register is not modified since that instruction and this is the valid value of `index` I've computed). In the third line the 8 bytes at `0x2b083e5b6f20+(8*234)` = `0x2b083e5b7670` are assigned to `rdx`, but those bytes are not 0:

```
(gdb) x/2 0x2b083e5b7670
0x2b083e5b7670: 0x3e578900  0x00002b08
```

How do `rdx` ends up with the 0 value?

I'm doing this on x86_64 Linux and this is a multithreaded program. Could this be a hardware error? The SIGSEV doesn't happen always.

Comment: Just to check, how did you get `0x2b083e5b6f20` as the base address for the array?

Comment: Yes I did get that address.

Comment: The question is, how? Because that can't be seen in your post.

Comment: I used gdb: `(gdb) p &array
$80 = (ui_fac_arr_t *) 0x2b083e5b6f20`

Comment: I hoped you did something more along the lines of `x/a 0x2b083e271250` because that's what the code is doing.

Comment: I can execute this also:
`(gdb) x/a 0x2b083e271250
0x2b083e271250: 0x2b083e5b6f20 <array>`
and I think this is the correct value, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this is a multithreaded program. The SIGSEV doesn't happen always.

It sounds like you may have a data race: after current thread loaded `array[index])->field` (which was 0 at the time) some other thread came in and wrote a different value there (you now observe the new value in the `core`).

> Could this be a hardware error?

Everything is possible, but a data race is 99.99% more probable.

Comment: Or a thread wrote a different value, this thread read 0, and then the different value was propagated to this CPU.

Comment: The array is supposed to be a "write-once" array, i.e. at program initialization the elements in the array get their value, but later the array is not modified. Actually I haven't even found any place in the code where this array is modified, the initialization code is generated during the build process.

Of course, there could be some other memory corruption bug...

Comment: I've changed the `array` and the structure pointed by `field` to be const in order to make sure that I get that rogue thread that modifies this data - and now it doesn't crash. Probably the memory layout also changed, so if there are any buffer overflows, it's not this data that gets modified - or if it's a hardware error, the different memory layout does not trigger it anymore.